# Coq - unify types from module functors with same parameters?

Tags: module, coq

How can I get Coq to recognise that two types, which are each imported from a module which is created from a module functor using the same argument, but appear in different modules, are actually the same type?

### Minimal example

```
Module Type S.
End S.

Module F (s : S).
Inductive foo : Type := a.
End F.

Module G (s : S).
Include F s.
End G.

Module H (s : S).
Include F.
End H.

Module I (s : S).

Module G := G s.
Module H := H s.

(* This is a type error - but the foos are the same! *)
Axiom bar : forall g : G.foo, forall h : H.foo, g = h.

End I.
```

In the above Coq file, I want to declare an axiom that requires that the type `foo` in `G s` be the same as the type `foo` in `H s`. Clearly, this is actually the case. But can I get Coq to recognise it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible. There is no structural equivalence between inductive types. By using `Include` twice, you are creating two different types. They happen to have the same name, but this is just a coincidence.

More generally, inductive types are badly supported by the module system. Any time you try something a bit fancy, Coq will complain that "The kernel does not recognize yet that a parameter can be instantiated by an inductive type."

As a rule of thumb, I suggest to always define inductive types outside module functors. I suppose that your type `foo` would depend on some property of module `s`, so you have to make it a bit more generic:

```
Module Type S.
Axiom t : Type.
End S.

Inductive foo (t : Type) : Type := a : t -> foo t.

Module F (s : S).
Definition foo := foo s.t.
End F.
```

Comment: "By using Include twice, you are creating two different types."... this has made my jaw drop. Do you know why such a design was chosen, or even desirable in the first place? It seems totally unreasonable.

Comment: The alternative doesn't seem more reasonable. By what mechanism could you even implement it?

Comment: I am not even sure people have a clear theoretical understanding of what it would mean for two families of inductive types to be equivalent, given all the nasty details of the universe hierarchy. (Keep in mind that these two types have universe constraints that might be different.) So, the situation is not satisfactory, but it is not going to change anytime soon.

Comment: @Li-yaoXia While I will confess to not knowing a huge amount about the CIC and other Coq theory - from a viewpoint of a software engineer, including a module should just expose access to its contents, not duplicate it entirely. Such systems have been implemented by basically every modern programming language. e.g. in Haskell, there is a distinction between referencing the same definition in a module in different places, vs identical definitions in different modules.

Comment: If you want to just expose access to the content of a module, use `Import`. But you will not be able to do `Import F`, because `F` is not a module, it is a module functor. So, you first have to create a module, e.g., `Module F' := F s. Import F'.`. But then it becomes apparent that you are creating two different modules `F'`, one in `G` and one in `H`.

Comment: For me it's not so apparent - neither `G` nor `H` are themselves modules either. It's only when using `G s` that the result is a module, and that only happens in `I`. At that point it seems to me that there is no reason to distinguish between the two `F'`, since it is known that they have the same `s`.

Comment: This is the difference between generative and applicative functors. One tends to find generative functors in pure settings, and applicative functors in impure ones. So, why is Coq using generative functors, while its setting is pure? As I explained before, Coq comes with universe constraints. And they somehow make the system impure. Indeed, any later definition can cause an earlier definition to be deeply modified, due to extra constraints. Just because `G` and `F` were created the same does not mean that they will keep the exact same universe constraints later on.

Comment: Previous comment should read "applicative functors in pure settings, and generative functors in impure ones"